# SQLite database crashing on reading

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, kotlin

I'm trying to create app for euro coins collecting, but my program can't access database, it crashed every time on hit line 'val db = readableDatabase', it was working and then i changed something and i tried to return it back but it doesn't work anymore, install uninstall app not working in others apps this code is running but i have one more app where this code goes successfully and then I add one more table and there i have same problem. So I thought that install uninstall app can solve that problem like reset database. Thanks for all help.

```
class DatabaseHelper(context: Context): SQLiteOpenHelper(context,
    DATABASE_NAME, null, 1) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME ($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "$COUNTRY_CODE TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                "$COIN_VALUE INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                "$OWNERSHIP INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                "$QUALITY INTEGER NOT NULL)"
        db!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
        fillTable()
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    private val listOfCodes = arrayOf(
        "AD", "BE", "CY", "DE",
        "EE", "FI", "FR", "GR",
        "NE", "IE", "LT", "LV",
        "LU", "MT", "MO", "PT",
        "AT", "SM", "SK", "SI",
        "ES", "IT", "VA")

    private fun fillTable(){...addingCoins...}
    // Like 
    //     insertData(listOfCodes[0], 1)
    //     insertData(listOfCodes[0], 2)
    //     insertData(listOfCodes[0], 5) etc.

    private fun insertData(code: String, coinValue: Int){
        val db = this.writableDatabase

        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COUNTRY_CODE, code)
        cv.put(COIN_VALUE, coinValue)
        cv.put(OWNERSHIP, 0)
        cv.put(QUALITY, 0)
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv)
    }

    fun updateOwnership(coinId: Int, newOwnership: Int){
        val db = writableDatabase

        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(OWNERSHIP, newOwnership)
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "$ID = $coinId", null)
    }

    fun updateQuality(coinId: Int, newQuality: Int){
        val db = writableDatabase

        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(QUALITY, newQuality)
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "$ID = $coinId", null)
    }

    fun getAllCoins(countryCode: String):ArrayList<Coins>{
        val coinsList = ArrayList<Coins>()
        val db = readableDatabase

        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(countryCode)
        val c: Cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $COUNTRY_CODE = ? ORDER BY $COIN_VALUE", selectionArgs)

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                val coinItem = Coins(
                    id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ID)),
                    country_code = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COUNTRY_CODE)),
                    coin_value = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COIN_VALUE)),
                    ownership = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(OWNERSHIP)) == 1,
                    quality = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QUALITY))
                )
                coinsList.add(coinItem)
            }while (c.moveToNext())
        }
        c.close()

        return coinsList
    }

    companion object{
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "Coins.db"
        const val TABLE_NAME = "coins_table"
        const val ID = "id"
        const val COUNTRY_CODE = "country_code"
        const val COIN_VALUE = "coin_value"
        const val OWNERSHIP = "ownership"
        const val QUALITY = "quality"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `get...Database()` recursively.

Your call to `getReadableDatabase()` triggers `onCreate()` that calls `fillTable()` that calls `insertData()` that calls `getWritableDatabase()`.

You cannot call `get...Database()` while `onCreate()` is executing. Instead, use the `SQLiteDatabase` that is passed as an argument to `onCreate()`.